# Watson is already running. Second session cannot be started

Tags: watson-studio, watson-studio-desktop

I have installed IBM watson studio but when i attempt to open it, I am getting an error stating " Watson is already running. Second session cannot be started"

Answer (score 1):

This problem is a result of Watson Studio being logged on two devices at the same time.

Please take the following steps:
You will need to log out from one device to use on another. 
You can perform this on myibm.ibm.com

Login in to https://myibm.ibm.com/dashboard/ 
Click 'Manage' on IBM Watson Studio Desktop 
Click on head next to 'Manage devices'

Manage Devices is a way to help the you remotely log out of one device in order to log in from another (and has the same effect as Sign out and Exit from within the SPSS Client). You simply click here 'Deactivate' and you should be able to use software on another computer.

Please let me know about further issues.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me after I updated to the new version. I had to kill the process from the task manager and now the studio doesn't start up and actually 'show' unless it was Run As Administrator. Try that out, kill the process and re-run it but as admin.